# Decryption password Encrypted using Encryptbypassphrase of SQL Server in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

I wan to Decrypt a value that was encrypted in SQL server (using function Encryptbypassphrase). I am using 3DES algo.

I have the value of Pass-phrase. But i am unable to decrypt is using PassPhrase as key in my Java Application.

Later on i came to know that PassPhrase is used to generate a Key and key generation Algo is not open.

Can any one please confirm this or can suggest anyway to achieve this(Decrypting SQL encrypted value in Java).

Can i achieve this ? if i use EncryptByKey Function of MS SQL. But i am not sure if we can generate the KEY without any passphrase for EncryptByKey function.

Kindly suggest or guide...

This one is Encryption in SQL and Decrypting in Java...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt in Java and Decrypt in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763196/encrypt-in-java-and-decrypt-in-ms-sql-server)

Comment: No both are different.
This one is Decrypt in Java and Encrypt in SQL server. 
the Link u shared is about 
Decrpt in in SQL Server  and Encrypt in Java. 

Both are different as SQL server does not take key to decrypt that we may pass from outside.